# Advice for getting professor to submit letter of recommendation

Tags: recommendation-letter, professorship

I'm applying to four master's programs. My former professor submitted his letter to the first two schools last month. But he has not submitted to the other two schools. One of them is rolling admissions so sooner the better, and the other had a "priority deadline" that passed last week so is now also rolling admissions. I've emailed him three times over the past 10 days but have not heard back.

One of the schools is clear that they won't look at your application until the letters are received.

I have the professor's cell number, should I text or call him about it? Should I give him more time before bothering him again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call or better visit in person if you can.  We all get a lot of email these days, maybe too much and it is too easy to overlook an email.  If you phone and the person recognizes the number he/she might ignore the call.

Comment: Your sentence about ignoring the call seems to advocate for going in person?

Comment: Yes.  Personally, I feel that we live in the information overload age and there are too many things (e.g., emails) that distract us from other work.  *Sometimes* the only way to get the help you need is to be there in person.

Comment: Thanks, I texted him as first step (I'm an hour away from campus) and he submitted them later that day.